# Forecasting Realized Volatility with Machine Learning

Tags: volatility, machine-learning, variance

How is the daily realized variance calculated for an intraday one minute data.

How can realized volatility be forecasted using machine learning techniques such as neural network and LSTM. Any detailed sample code for the forecasting technique as well as the code for HAR-RV.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to execute considering you have RV column in your dataset

```python
For HAR-RV: 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Simulate some data for df['RV']
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'RV': np.random.rand(100)})

# Calculate lagged RV features
df['RV_lag_d'] = df['RV'].shift(1)
df['RV_lag_w'] = df['RV'].rolling(window=5).mean().shift(1)
df['RV_lag_m'] = df['RV'].rolling(window=22).mean().shift(1)

# Drop NaN rows
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Prepare data
X = df[['RV_lag_d', 'RV_lag_w', 'RV_lag_m']]
y = df['RV']

# Fit HAR-RV model
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

# For ML : 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# Fit Random Forest model
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
rf_model.fit(X, y)
```